# xltabular exceeds lower page boundaries

Tags: xltabular

I managed to boil the problem down to this minimal example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Everything}

    
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \FloatBarrier
    
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}[h]{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\FloatBarrier
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    
    \FloatBarrier
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ |X|l| }
        
        \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
                test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
                test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
        test & test \\ \hline
    \end{xltabular}
    \FloatBarrier
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    
    \FloatBarrier
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ |X|l|l|l| }
        
        \hline      
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        test &        test & test &       test \\ \hline
        
        
    \end{xltabular}
\FloatBarrier
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[height=9cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, the last figure is partly outside the page. It should be on the next page. I have this problem at multiple places inside the document. If the `[h]` option is not being used on the figures, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: xltabular does not have an `[h]` option, and like `tabularx` requires at least one `X` column.

Comment: your example produces [this output in texlive2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK1E7.png)

Comment: changed your points of the first comment -> same Problem! 
Interesting, I am using TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian).

Comment: using overleaf I get the correct page breaks in texlive2022 and texlive2021 but the bad output you show in texlive2020 and earlier.

Comment: updated Texlive to 2022 and as you said, the problem for this example disappeared. BUT: The problem still persists. I found a new example and edited my post.